# Set id in dynamic edittext and textview

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, textview

I have some troubles trying to put an id to a dynamic edittext and texview in Android Studio, i want to use this id to get the id's in another functions.
Note: Im not setting any id in the onCreate function.

This is my code:

```
            for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : getMap(newContact).entrySet()) {
            total++;
            TextView ProgrammaticallyTextView = new TextView(this.getActivity());
            EditText ProgrammaticallyEditText = new EditText(this.getActivity());
            ProgrammaticallyTextView.setId(total);
            ProgrammaticallyEditText.setId(total+1);
            ProgrammaticallyTextView.setText(entry.getKey());
            ProgrammaticallyEditText.setText(entry.getValue());

            linearLayout.addView(ProgrammaticallyTextView);
            linearLayout.addView(ProgrammaticallyEditText);

            total++;
        }
```

This is the function that i use the edittext and textview id's

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.btn_create:

            String test = "";

            for(int i=0; i < (this.total); i+=2){
                TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(i++);
                EditText et = (EditText) v.findViewById(i+2);
                if ((i+2) >= this.total){
                    test += tv.getText()+"="+et.getText();
                }else
                {
                    test += tv.getText()+"="+et.getText()+",";
                }

            }

            mContact = getMap(test);
            newContactRequest();
            break;

    }
}
```

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly change the data type to string. Just writing i++ tries to assign that value as an integer. 
I think if you change your lines to these it should work.

```
TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(String.valueOf(i++));
EditText et = (EditText) v.findViewById(String.valueOf(i+2));
```